# Deleting matching items from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of values. I would like to remove values which cancel to each other (+ and -). The values are randomly in the list, so I first added a new column in excel with the absolute values. I then sorted on the absolute values so the amounts which needs to be cancelled are below each other.

I was thinking to create a for loop and sum up the ifrst row with the second row, and when this sums to zero, delete both rows and start from the top again. Please refer to the picture of an example. I have marked yellow the items which should be deleted. As I only want to delete matching items, the total sum of the amount column should not change after the operation.

[image: example]

Currently I have something like this

> for i in df["Amount in Entity Currency"]:
> if df["Amount in Entity Currency"][i] + df["Amount in Entity Currency"][i+1] == 0:
> df.drop(df[df["Amount in Entity Currency"][i]])
> df.drop(df[df["Amount in Entity Currency"][i + 1]])

Comment: Hi Jon! Thanks for your reply and advice! A good point, which also will improve my skills. Will try to think of a way to do this myself and then edit the question.

Comment: If you want a nudge getting started, I might create two sorted lists of positive and negative numbers then walk them together perhaps based on index of using `next()` picking out matches to discard.

Comment: If a `0` is possible in the list how do one or more `0`s cancel each other?

Comment: Good point! I have looked in to the dataset and dont see any 0 values, so luckily not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

try sth like this after you have sorted the list (as you already said):

```
for i,elem in enumerate(yourList):
    nextElem = yourList[i+1]
    if (elem + nextElem < 0.00000001): 
        yourList.remove(elem)
        yourList.remove(nextElem)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I unfortunately get the following error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'remove'. Do I need to import a certain library?

Answer (score 0):

I would base an answer off of several building blocks. First is creating two "iterable" sub-lists. One for positive numbers and the other negative numbers.

Then I would iterate over both of them using `next()` and as long as one of the two lists had values I would act on the current values as appropriate.

```py
import random

full_data = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(20)] + [-random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(20)]

zeros = [i for i in full_data if i == 0]
positives = iter(sorted([i for i in full_data if i > 0]))
negatives = iter(sorted([i for i in full_data if i < 0], reverse=True))

## ------------------------------
## prime the list with zero or 1 0s where an odd number of 0s
## results in [0] as the evens cancel each other out.
## ------------------------------
result = [0] * (len(zeros) % 2)
## ------------------------------

pos = next(positives, None)
neg = next(negatives, None)
while pos is not None or neg is not None:
    if pos is None:
        # we ran out of positive numbers so add any remaining negatives
        result.extend([neg] + list(negatives))
        break

    if neg is None:
        # we ran out of negative numbers so add any remaining positives
        result.extend([pos] + list(positives))
        break

    if pos == -neg:
        # these results cancel each other
        pos = next(positives, None)
        neg = next(negatives, None)

    elif pos > -neg:
        # this positive is "larger" then this negative so add the negative
        result.append(neg)
        neg = next(negatives, None)

    else:
        # this positive is "smaller" than this negative so add the positive
        result.append(pos)
        pos = next(positives, None)

print(f"The original list has {len(full_data)} items and sums to: {sum(full_data)}")
print(f"The filtered list has {len(result)} items and sums to: {sum(result)}")
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! This actually worked on my data set. I only have a small problem, the list/column was part of a bigger data set. And when using this code I lose all the other columns. I tried to fix this by replacing "positives" with df["positives"], which I guess creates a new column in my data set (df). BUt this results in the following error: TypeError: object of type 'list_iterator' has no len()  Any idea how this can be solved? Or is there a beter way to keep all other columns?

Comment: I think you can get the same thing by sorting you main dataframe into two and using next() on iterrows() to achieve the same thing.